# add new div element after input text and add css

Tags: jquery, css

I have an html form with input types texts and radio button with class = required. I am trying to validate the form. On submit of the form I need to validate the form and if it returns false, I need to add a new div (text "Please fill in the required field") and display it below the field in red. If the user fills in that field, it should become green color or red color should disappear. jQuery is in separate js file. So on click of the submit button I am doing the following

```
$('#test_form .required').filter(':visible').each(function() {
var input = $(this);
if($(this).is(':empty')){
    $(this).css("border","2px solid #FF0004");
    $(this).after('<div>Please fill in the required field</div>');
    return = false;
}else{
    return true;
}
});
```

There are couple of problems occurring now.
1. required text is coming below the fields.I need that in red color and font size - 10px. So how can I add css to the newly added div?
2. Consider there is a radio group of 5 radio button. So I need the Required text only if atleast one is not selected and display the text below that radio group. Now the Required text is coming for all the radio buttons.
3. Also if the user clicks submit 4 times, the text gets added 4 times for each field. I think this we can handle using a flag

Can anyone please guide me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. required text is coming below the fields.I need that in red color and font size - 10px. So how can I add css to the newly added div?

What about adding css ? Just add a class to the newly created **div**. That could help you better **position your div** and add other css.

Modify

```
$(this).after('<div>Please fill in the required field</div>');
```

to

```
$(this).after('<div class="info">Please fill in the required field</div>');
```

And in **CSS**

```
<style>
.info{
background:#FFB0B0;
color:#FF0000;
}
</style>
```

> `2.` Consider there is a radio group of 5 radio button. So I need the Required text only if atleast one is not selected and display the text
>   below that radio group. Now the Required text is coming for all the
>   radio buttons.
>
> `3.` Also if the user clicks submit 4 times, the text
>   gets added 4 times for each field.

Adding a flag could fix these problems

Comment: Thanks Mevin..now the class for the text is coming correctly..For the radio group, in the code they have kept class="required" for all the radio buttons and that could be the reason the text is coming for all the 5 radio buttons..

Answer (score 0):

you have to set **errorPlacement** section of [jQuery validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) function.

```
$("#form").validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true
        },
        firstname: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        name: {
            required: "Enter name"
        },
        firstname: {
            required: "Enter firstname"
        }
    },
    errorPlacement: function ($error, $element) {
        var name = $element.attr("name");

        $("#error" + name).append($error);
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/R3aEQ/

Comment: Hi Chirag, Thanks for your reply. Yes using jquery validator plugin we can do this. But we dont want to use that as there are lots of elements which will need a change and we have very min time for that. So we are trying the above method.